# Reading few columns of Excel( .xls) file in Java

Tags: java, excel, xls, xlsx

I have a multi columns xls file that i want to read.
Is there any Java  code that reads the data from any two column(The name of two columns are "Name" & "GUID") and print it on console(I want to perform few operations from the data of those two columns.The process should continue until all the rows for those colums are read are read.
Kindly help me.

Also will the code for reading XLXS file would differ?

Answer (score 2):

You shoudl check out the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) libraries.

> For .xls files, there is org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.ExcelExtractor,
>   which will return text, optionally with formulas instead of their
>   contents. Those using POI 3.5 can also use
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.extractor.XSSFExcelExtractor, to perform a similar
>   task for .xlsx files.

See [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/HSSFReadWrite.java) for how to read an Excel file